# Что такое "гепева"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика, смысл

Из "Поднятой целины":

*Гепева по вас горько плачет.*

Гугл вообще не знает такого слова, не знаю, куда и сунуться... Понятно, конечно, что имеется в виду что-то вроде тюрьмы, но хочется всё-таки где-то найти это слово.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ГПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9D%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%94_%D0%A0%D0%A1%D0%A4%D0%A1%D0%A0) —> гепеву́, гепева́ (на украинский манер).

«**Гепева** — так у народі називали ҐПУ, перейменовану ЧК»; «Есть там, конечно, и уполномоченный **гепеву**. Заседает в комнате с табличкой «Дежурный по станции» ([Василь Шкляр. Залишенець](https://lib.com.ua/ru/book/zalishenets/?page=111)).

«І їх дітям **Гепева** ніколи не простить того, що вона повбивала їх батьків…» (Тодось Осьмачка).

> Много раз сталкиваясь с цыганами в оперативной работе, я всегда примечал: цыгане-одиночки не любят огнестрельного оружия. Зато ножи у них — будь здоров!
> Красивый, отточенный, как бритва, в шагреневых с серебром ножнах, оказался и у этого.
> — Садись, Рома! Побеседуем.
> — **Гепева**, што ли? – он наконец стал соображать.
> — Вроде, Рома… Вроде… – я обратил внимание на его землистое лицо. – Бежал из домзака?
> — Бежал… Ково уж тут? А кому охота летом кичеванить?..
> — «Скамеешник»? Конокрад?
> [Георгий Лосьев. У чужих берегов (сборник)](https://booksonline.com.ua/view.php?book=182954&page=23)

Comment: Браво, Римма! Спасибо большое!))

Comment: И тебе, Артём, поклон — и за вопрос, и за оценку. Всё. Сплю...